# adding class to PARENT when any child is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.custom_item').on('click', function (evt) {
        var $button = jQuery(this);
        var $tr = $button.closest('div'); //better change here to closest
        var $div = $tr.find('.detail_block'); //current div
        jQuery('.detail_block').not($div).slideUp(); //hide all other div's not the current one
        $div.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

how can I add a "open" class to `.customer_wrap` when and of the `.detail_block` are opened?

I tried different ways but can't seem to make it work. If someone could give me a hand on this. Thank you

here is the fiddle example for you to understand exactly what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/3xq7t2yh/

Comment: why you dont use just jQuery(".detail_block").addClass("opened");

Comment: I'm trying to add the "open" class to the parent DIV, you can see the fiddle to see what I mean

Comment: yeah and your example is confusing because .detail_block isnt parent to .customer_wrap  it is child.

Comment: sorry I don't know english so good, I meant child then )

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do but try this and see if this is what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/3xq7t2yh/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check any of .detail_block divs visible or not  .. and use this code inside slideToggle() callback function

```
if(jQuery('.detail_block:visible').length > 0){
 // div open
}else{
  // div close
}
```

your full code

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        jQuery('.custom_item').on('click', function (evt) {
            var $button = jQuery(this);
            var $tr = $button.parent();//better change here to closest
            var $div = $button.find('.detail_block');//current div
            jQuery('.detail_block').not($div).slideUp(); //hide all other div's not the current one
            $div.slideToggle(200, function(){
               if(jQuery('.detail_block:visible').length > 0){
                 // div open
                 $tr.addClass('open');
                }else{
                  // div close
                  $tr.removeClass('open');
                } 
            });
       });      
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3xq7t2yh/3/)

another way

```
if($div.is(':visible')){
             // div open
                    $tr.addClass('open');
          }else{
              // div close
                  $tr.removeClass('open');
          }
```

your full code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
    jQuery('.custom_item').on('click', function (evt) {
        var $button = jQuery(this);
        var $tr = $button.parent();//better change here to closest
        var $div = $button.find('.detail_block');//current div
        jQuery('.detail_block').not($div).slideUp(); //hide all other div's not the current one
       $div.slideToggle(200, function(){
         if($div.is(':visible')){
             // div open
                    $tr.addClass('open');
          }else{
              // div close
                  $tr.removeClass('open');
          } 
        });
    });   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3xq7t2yh/4/)

Explain:  this code will add class "open" to .customer_wrap div if any of .detail_block is visible .. but if its all hidden  it will remove class "open" from .customer_wrap